# Python: Drawing in Turtle window says 'Not Responding'

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a square using Python turtle graphics using a `for` loop. I am able to draw the square but the turtle window says 'Not Responding'. Adding my code below:

```
import turtle;

Bq = turtle.Turtle()

Bq.shape("turtle")

for i in range(4):

      Bq.fd(100)

      Bq.lt(90)

Bq.done()
```

Comment: This code should fail with, "AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'done'".  Instead of `Bq.done()`, it should be `turtle.done()` as turtle instances don't implement `done()`.  The `Not Responding` message is not coming from turtle -- please describe your environment, e.g. are you running this under Python IDLE, etc.

Comment: I am using spyder

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one?
I created a function named `draw_square`:

```
def draw_square(some_turtle):
for i in range(1, 5):
    some_turtle.forward(100)
    some_turtle.right(90)
```

Then in your main function you can invoke the `draw_square` function.

Example:

```
def draw_art():    
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("white")

#Create the turtle some_square - Draws a square
some_square = turtle.Turtle()
some_square.shape("turtle")
some_square.color("black")
some_square.speed(3)
some_square.right(20)

for i in range(1, 37):
    draw_square(some_square)
    some_square.right(10)
```

Lastly, call the `draw_art`:

```
draw_art()
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much whaangbuu for your response. Actually I am a beginner in python, when i have used your code, brad.right throws name undefined. The Window is still showing not responding.

Comment: Sorry @RathishMK I've updated my answer/code. Use `some_square.right(10)` instead.

Hope that helps bud!

Comment: I am still getting the 'Not Responding' error. When I try the below code it comes properly - import turtle;

bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
turtle.mainloop(). But When i use the for loop there is something going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle;

def drawSquare(TurtleName):
    TurtleName.shape("turtle")
    TurtleName.color("yellow")
    TurtleName.speed(3)
    for i in range(4):
        TurtleName.fd(100)
        TurtleName.rt(90)
    turtle.mainloop()    

bob = turtle.Turtle()
drawSquare(bob)
```

By adding turtle.mainloop() at the end I am able to avoid the Not Responding error.

Comment: That places the program in an infinite loop, at least in spyder.

Answer (score 0):

In my PyCharm IDE and Windows 10 platform, using `turtle.mainloop()` at the end of the code solved the problem.