# Python Turtle window crashes every 2nd time running

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The code below is a basic square drawing using Turtle in python.

Running the code the first time works. But running the code again activates a Turtle window that is non-responsive and subsequently crashes every time.

The error message includes `raise Terminator` and `Terminator`

Restarting kernel in Spyder (Python 3.6 on a Dell Desktop) fixes the problem in that I can then run the code again successfully, but the root cause is a mystery?

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637723/python-drawing-in-turtle-window-says-not-responding) to another question that is similar but as yet unanswered.

Please +1 this question if you find it worthy of an answer!!

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
for i in range(4):
    bob.fd(100)
    bob.lt(90)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probably a long shot, but have your tried the `turtle.bye()` suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43297726/5771269)?  Note that `turtle.done()` is a synonym for `turtle.mainloop()` so this is one of those rare cases where you put code, the `turtle.bye()`, after the `turtle.mainloop()` call.

Comment: cdlane - it worked! Please post as an answer - I'll put the check by correct answer for sure.

Comment: Daniel, if you could up vote the answer in the link, that would be sufficient and appreciated.  It would help confirm that is a solution to this problem in general and perhaps this question will be folded into being a duplicate of that other.

Comment: This code works fine for me. Is this a Spyder-specific problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this will seem wholly unsatisfactory, but I have found that creating the turtle with:

```
try:
    tess = turtle.Turtle()
except:
    tess = turtle.Turtle()
```

works (that is, eliminates the "working every other time" piece.  I also start with

```
wn = turtle.Screen()
```

and end with

```
from sys import platform
if platform=='win32':
    wn.exitonclick()
```

Without those parts, if I try to move the turtle graphics windows in Windows, things break.  (running Spyder for Python 3.6 on a Windows machine)
edit: of course, OSX is perfectly happy without the exitonclick() command and unhappy with it so added platform specific version of ending "feature fix."  The try...except part is still needed for OSX.

Answer (score 0):

The module uses a class variable _RUNNING which remains true between executions when running in spyder instead of running it as a self contained script. I have requested for the module to be updated.

Meanwhile, work around/working example beyond what DukeEgr93 has proposed

1)

```
import importlib
import turtle

importlib.reload(turtle)

bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
for i in range(4):
    bob.fd(100)
    bob.lt(90)

turtle.mainloop()
```

2. 

```
import importlib
import turtle

turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING=True
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
for i in range(4):
    bob.fd(100)
    bob.lt(90)

turtle.mainloop()
```