# Python Turtle fails to run or crashes every other time running

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Just a preface I know very little about coding as I am in my first semester of learning.

Every other time I run a file with turtle in it, it just doesn't work and I usually get an error like:
 File "", line 5, in forward

Terminator

Even for super simple instances like:

```
from turtle import *
forward(90)
done()
```

It'll run the first time perfectly fine, then the second time it'll give me that error, then the 3rd time it works fine, then the 4th it's the error, etc etc.
I've imported turtle a couple different ways, such as "import turtle", "import turtle as tr", "from turtle import *". I don't know if that changes anything but I include it just for more context. The only way I've found it to work is using the weird command lines given as an answer here: [Python Turtle window crashes every 2nd time running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438762/python-turtle-window-crashes-every-2nd-time-running)
but I need to be able to run it in a loop because I have to make a hangman game. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: do you run it from console/terminal/cmd.exe - `python script.py` - or from some editor or IDE like PyCharm or IDLE ?

Comment: I run it through spyder @furas